# Rails: Stub client-side ajax call in feature spec

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I'm writing an rspec feature spec to test a file upload page that sends files directly from the client to S3 using the [s3_direct_upload](https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload) gem. Instead of hitting S3, I'd like to stub out that link and return the correct response so I can test the behavior after a failed/successful ajax request.

I think my issue lies in the fact that I can't use WebMock to stub requests, since the request isn't fired from the server (it's happening on the client).

#### Changing the test type/framework

I could add a new testing dependency like Jasmine or Sinon and test the js/page directly, but that still leaves me with feature specs that are trying to hit S3.

#### Changing the url

All of the bucket/path information for the link to S3 is bundled with the gem, so I would have to patch it in the test env, which I'd like to avoid.

### Question

How I can run a feature spec that stubs out a client-side ajax request?